# Order items by last upload -> first show

Tags: php, sorting, items, projects

I'm working on a website for a friend of mine. Someone made a CMS for me and placed the website on it.

Now i'm busy with finetuning. The thing is, the website launches projects. Only the last uploaded project end up as last on the website instead of up front.

So I wanted to show the recent uploaded project as first. And the first uploaded project as last. Is here a code for how to order this?

The website what this is about can be viewed on http://tinyurl.com/p36hz6u
The order can bee seen at Portfolio -> Objects -> Now the first shown in list is Shine a Light on me. This one must be last and Roling on grils must be at first. Its now Z->A and it has to be A->Z.

This is the html / php

```
 <div class="portfoliomenu">
  <?php foreach ($portfolioCategories as $category) { ?>

    <a class="w-inline-block portfoliolink" href="#" onClick="swapCategory(<?=$category[ID]?>)"><img class="w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny" data-lightbox="roadtrip" src="includes/uploads/<?=$category[IMAGE]?>" height="20"><img class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium" src="includes/uploads/<?=$category[IMAGE]?>" height="15">
    </a>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

This is the PHP

```
              <div class="w-row portfoliorow">
      <div class="w-col w-col-2 portfolioarrowleft">
      <?php if ($page != 1 && $pages > 1) { ?>
      <a href="#" onClick="slidePortfolio(-1,<?=$objects[0][CATEGORY_ID]?>)"><img src="includes/images/left.png" width="30" alt="548818b8ba4bc2be7fd987c7_left.png"></a>
      <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php
      $i = 0;
       foreach ($objects as $object) { ?>
      <div class="w-col w-col-2">
        <a class="w-inline-block portfolioobjectlink" href="#" onClick="swapProduct(<?=$object[ID]?>)"><img src="includes/php/afbeelding.php?afbeelding=<?=$object[IMAGE1]?>&breedte=150&hoogte=150" alt="548828104511409e78b0c627_150x150.gif">
          <div><?= $object[TITLE]?></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php $i++; } ?>
      <?php if ($i < 4) { 
        for($j = 0; $j < 4-$i; $j++)
        {
      ?>
      <div class="w-col w-col-2">
      </div>

      <?php }
      } ?>
      <div class="w-col w-col-2 portfolioarrowright">
      <?php if ($page < $pages) { ?>
      <a href="#" onclick="slidePortfolio(1,<?=$objects[0][CATEGORY_ID]?>)"><img src="includes/images/right.png" alt="5488189c4511409e78b0c518_right.png"></a>
      <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I hope you guys can help me out and understand me. (Sorry for the English)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide more information. Ideally provide code where loop or something that outputs projects to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming items in `$objects` are inputted in project order (first to latest) use [krsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) on the array to reverse order by keys since items would retain key values as 0, 1, 2, ...

```
$i = 0;
krsort(objects);
foreach ($objects as $object) { ?>
...
```

Alternatively, you can use [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) which reverses the order of the elements in an array:

```
$i = 0;
foreach (array_reverse($objects) as $object) { ?>
...
```

Finally, if there is a `date` element inside `$objects` array you can sort by that element using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function datesort($a, $b) {
   return $a['date'] - $b['date'];
}

usort($objects,'datesort');

$i = 0;
foreach ($objects as $object) { ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!! This helped me sorting the projects. One more thing, the objects are shown by 4, and than a next button, and than 4 more etc. As u can see in the portfolio. The site now sorts just per 4. Is there a option to change this trough all the projects? Thanks so far.

Comment: Your post does not show where `$objects` is first created. Sort at its source where projects are first inserted into the array. If originating from database, use `Order By` clause in SQL.